# printing a character as many times as a specific value

Tags: python, loops

how can I print a character as many times as a specific value.
for example, I want to print "----" as many times as the user enters a number.
if the user enters 3, I want to repeat "----" 3 times and so on.

Comment: What *do* you know about loops in Python?

Comment: `print('-'*3)` will do

Answer (score 1):

take user input

```
n = int(input('Enter your Number'))
```

then run a `for loop` for given number

```
for _ in range(n):
    print("----",end=" ")
```